# Restify CORS not working for POST request

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I'm using **restify** for my application. The cross origin requests works fine for **GET** with restify's CORS but shows following error for **POST** request.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1337/path/add. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

The code for enabling CORS i've used is:

```
    server.use(restify.CORS());
```

as per its [documentation](http://mcavage.me/node-restify). Can anyone suggest me how to make the **POST** request work

Comment: share the complete http post request including headers and body.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem this morning, the change that worked for me was to change:

```
server.use(restify.CORS());
```

To:

```
server.pre(restify.CORS());
server.use(restify.fullResponse());
```

the server.**pre** being the important bit. I found a bug relating to an error in the documentation:

https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/573

Answer (score 1):

use  [restify-cors-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-cors-middleware)
  Procedure:

in root file let say app.js or index.js or server.js whatever you named

```
 const cors     = require('./cors');

 const server = restify.createServer({
  name    : 'name',
  version : 'version',
  url     : 'server url'
});

server.pre(cors.preflight);

server.use(cors.actual)
```

cors.js

```
   const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');

   const cors = corsMiddleware({
   preflightMaxAge: 5,
   origins: ['*'],
   allowHeaders: ['*','token'],
   exposeHeaders: ['*','token']
  })

   module.exports = cors
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, solved with this:

```
restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('authorization');
server.pre(restify.CORS());
server.use(restify.fullResponse());
```

That's assuming you have an authorisation header, for example for a bearer token.